# How to write on existing excel files without losing previous information using python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, append

I need to write a program to scrap daily quote from a certain web page and collect them into a single excel file. I wrote something which finds next empty row and starts writing new quotes on it but deletes previous rows too:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('gold_quote.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')
.
.
.
z = 1
x = sheet['A{}'.format(z)].value

while x != None:
    x = sheet['A{}'.format(z)].value
    z += 1

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('quote.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1',na_rep='', float_format=None,columns=['Date', 'Time', 'Price'], header=True,index=False, index_label=None, startrow=z-1, startcol=0, engine=None,merge_cells=True, encoding=None, inf_rep='inf', verbose=True, freeze_panes=None)
writer.save()
```

Comment: It sounds like you are compiling a list of strings.  Why not have it be a line delimited txt file instead?  Each line could be its own entry.

Comment: I need excel file for further processing. I can write on excel file with this code but while updating each day previous rows will be removed.

Comment: Sounds similar to when you open a file with write vs append status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, first we should define a reader to read existing data of excel file then concatenate recently extracted data from web with a defined writer, and we should drop duplicates otherwise any time the program is executed there will be many duplicated data. Then we can write previous and new data altogether:

```
excel_reader = pd.ExcelFile('gold_quote.xlsx')
to_update = {"Sheet1": df}

excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('gold_quote.xlsx')

for sheet in excel_reader.sheet_names:
    sheet_df = excel_reader.parse(sheet)
    append_df = to_update.get(sheet)

    if append_df is not None:
        sheet_df = pd.concat([sheet_df, df]).drop_duplicates()

    sheet_df.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet, index=False)

excel_writer.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Question**: How to write on existing excel files without losing previous information

`openpyxl` uses `append` to write after last used Row:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('gold_quote.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

rowData = ['2017-08-01', '16:31', 1.23]
sheet.append(rowData)

wb.save('gold_quote.xlsx')
```

Comment: everything looks good unless it cannot append padnas DataFrame format. It says cannot convert to Excel.

Comment: The type of ultimate data should be appended is: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Comment: @Farhad: You have to convert `pandas.DataFrame` to `list` and `append` Row by Row from List or `iterate pandas.DataFrame`.

Comment: The data appended after 13 empty rows . why ?

Answer (score 0):

```
writer.book = wb
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in wb.worksheets)
```

Comment: adding this code at ending part does exactly the same thing, should I remove anything from my code in order to keep previous rows while executing each time?

Comment: Add it atfer this line: writer = pd.ExcelWriter('quote.xlsx')

Comment: while executing this error comes up: xl_format = self.book.add_format()
AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_format'